# Replace values in dataframe by matching dates of different lengths

Tags: r, date, replace, dplyr, left-join

I have 52 time series files with differing lengths for date. All have the same end date - 31-01-2017, but all 52 dataframes have different start dates.

'data': nRows

```
Date        FLOW     Modelled
01-01-1992  1.856    NA
02-01-1992  1.523    NA
03-01-1992  2.623    NA    
04-01-1992  3.679    NA
...
31-12-2017
```

I also have a file with simulated FLOW values for each of the datasets in columns.

'Simulated': 20819 rows, 53 columns (including Date).

```
Date        1        2          3       ..52
01-01-1961  1.856    2.889      2.365
02-01-1961  1.523    3.536      4.624
03-01-1961  2.536    2.452      6.352    
04-01-1961  3.486    4.267      3.685
...
31-12-2017
```

**My question is I want to select each column from Simulated data (e.g column 1 corresponds to 'data' file 1) and fill the Modelled column of 'data' with the simulated values. Ideally this would loop through the 52 files based on a list of their names**

The problem I am facing is when using left_join the error I get is

```
 e.g.  replacement has 20819 rows, data has 9657
```

when 'data' is a shorter than 'Simulated', and

```
 e.g.  replacement has 20819 rows, data has 22821
```

when 'data' is longer than 'Simulated'.

I have tried to use left_join of the `dplyr` package with no luck as dates are not matching up across 'data' and 'Simulated' dataframes.

```
library(dplyr)
df <-left_join(data, Simulated, by = c("Date"),all.x=TRUE)
```

I have formatted both 'data' and 'Simulated' dates using similar to `Simulated$Date <- as.Date(with(Simulated, paste(Year, Month, Day, sep="-")), "%Y-%m-%d")`. But I still get the error below when using left_join:

```
cannot join a Date object with an object that is not a Date object
```

Comment: Doesn't this suggest that `data$Date` is not a `Date` object? R's default formatting for a date is `%Y-%m-%d`, further suggesting your `date` data contains strings there.

Comment: In the absence of a response to the comment and looking at the question which is not reproducible in the absence of code that would create a suitable couple of data-objects for `left_join` operation, suggesting we vote to close as off-topic.  close reasoning: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [MCVE]."

Comment: @r2evans I did not realise that data$Date was not a Date object. I formatted the dates of data previously in my code and wrote it out to .csv and I naively thought the formatting would remain when reading them back in. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Writing to CSV preserves very little. If done correctly, then `integer`, `numeric`, and `character` will be preserved, but that's about it. (Try `str(read.csv(text=paste(c('1,1.2,"1"',Sys.time(),Sys.Date()),collapse=','),header=F))` and `str(read.csv(text=paste(c('1,1.2,"1"',as.character(Sys.time()),as.character(Sys.Date())),collapse=','),header=F,stringsAsFactors=F))` to see.)

Comment: @r2evans Noted! Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be achieved using `tidyverse` and `read.table`. First read all data frames from all files in a list and then use `dplyr::bind_rows` to merge them in one dataframe.

```
#Get the file list
filelist = list.files(path = ".", pattern = ".*.txt", full.names = TRUE)
# Read all files in a list
ll <- lapply(filelist, FUN=read.table, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Read data from file containing simulate data
simulated <- read.table(file = "simulated.txt", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(tidyverse)

#Convert simulated data to long format and then join with other dataframes
simulated %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
  gather(df_num, SIM_FLOW, -Date) %>% 
  mutate(df_num = gsub("X(\\d+)", "\\1", df_num)) %>%
  right_join(bind_rows(ll, .id="df_num") %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")),
             by=c("df_num", "Date"))


#          Date df_num SIM_FLOW   FLOW Modelled
# 1  1992-01-01      1     1.86   1.86       NA
# 2  1992-01-02      1       NA   1.52       NA
# 3  1992-01-03      1       NA   2.62       NA
# 4  1992-01-04      1       NA   3.68       NA
# 5  1993-01-01      2       NA  11.86       NA
# 6  1993-01-02      2     3.54  11.52       NA
# 7  1993-01-03      2       NA  12.62       NA
# 8  1993-01-04      2       NA  13.68       NA
# 9  1994-01-01      3       NA 111.86       NA
# 10 1994-01-02      3       NA 111.52       NA
# 11 1994-01-03      3     6.35 112.62       NA
# 12 1994-01-04      3       NA 113.68       NA
```

**Data:**

```
simulated.txt

Date        1        2          3
01-01-1992  1.856    2.889      2.365
02-01-1993  1.523    3.536      4.624
03-01-1994  2.536    2.452      6.352    
04-01-1902  3.486    4.267      3.685


File1.txt

Date        FLOW     Modelled
01-01-1992  1.856    NA
02-01-1992  1.523    NA
03-01-1992  2.623    NA    
04-01-1992  3.679    NA

File2.txt

Date        FLOW     Modelled
01-01-1993  11.856    NA
02-01-1993  11.523    NA
03-01-1993  12.623    NA    
04-01-1993  13.679    NA

File3.txt

Date        FLOW     Modelled
01-01-1994  111.856    NA
02-01-1994  111.523    NA
03-01-1994  112.623    NA    
04-01-1994  113.679    NA
```